# JQuery :contains find first and single instance of a string

Tags: jquery

The Jquery :contains function is very good in that it will find an instance of a string. However what if I am performing this contains: function on a table which in the second column contains the following.

```
0
20
01
44
```

The code below when run on the above table with the column values will return every row where there is a "0". SO basically every row except "44".

```
$('.application>tbody>tr') 
.show() 
.find("td:nth-child(2).not(':contains("0")') 
.parent() 
.hide() 
}
```

How would one go about making the code return only the rows where there is a single "0" and not the other rows which contain a "0" such as "20".

Hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this, for example:

```
$('.application>tbody>tr') 
.show() 
.find("td:nth-child(2)")
.filter(function() { return $.text([this]) != "0"; })
.parent() 
.hide()
```

This compares the *exact* text, rather than a substring.

Comment: That makes sense, however I get a "$.text is not a function" in firebug. Any ideas?

Comment: @Lord - which version of jQuery are you on?  The long version is `$(this).text() != "0";`, it's just wasteful.

Comment: @Lord - oo, very old indeed, use `$(this).text()` instead of `$.text([this])` then, or upgrade to a later version (current is 1.4.4).